# image is getting cached , but not getting displayed?

Tags: html

I have an image :

```
<img id="img1" src="http://igyaan.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Nvidia-580x362.jpg" />
```

The image from the url is getting cached, but image is not getting displayed.

I analysed it using firebug, where I could see a GET request to the image, and image is returned.  And in addition, there is a request to some facebook pic which I never requested (firebug: Bad request):

```
http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/424831_319096764809781_1948053300_n.jpg
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Qb6YX/5/

Any idea why this is happening? And how do i solve this issue?
**MoreInfo :** iam working on  a Rss feed reader , it  displays images of posts . I had trouble with this specific website.

Comment: Your `Nvidia-580x362.jpg` sends a `Location: http://a1.sphotos.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-snc7/424831_319096764809781_1948053300_n.jpg` header.  Your image is redirecting to the facebook one.

Comment: Your image seems to do this redirection - for whatever reason you'd have to check out on server side. What gets cached is only the `302 found` redirection

Comment: Some sort of hotlink protection?

Comment: Are you hosting the image on your server, or trying to load it from somewhere else? I've tried it and it tried to load the image from facebook. I suspect the image's host is trying to stop you hot-linking the image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the image is hotlink-protected. That's why it gets redirected when you try to load it on your page. In this case you should use a server-side proxy to retrieve the image and load it from there.

Using an external service from [Images.weserv.nl](http://images.weserv.nl):

```
<img src="http://images.weserv.nl/?url=igyaan.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Nvidia-580x362.jpg" />
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esCEj/)

It would be better if you host the proxy script on your server for this purpose so that you have fewer dependencies for your RSS feed reader.

However, there are times when we should respect the site owner's decision of hotlink protection. One way to go about it is to replace an image that cannot be loaded with a default one.